# Why does boolval(false) return empty in php?

Tags: php

I'm a little confused how the php function `boolval` works. Consider the following

`<?php echo boolval(true); // prints 1`

And contrast with

`<?php echo boolval(false); // prints nothing?`

Why am I not getting back either true/false? And why is `boolval(false)` returning nothing?

I ran into this problem while trying to parse `$argv` for a boolean argument. What's the correct of extracting a bool value from `$argv` if not with this function?

Comment: `var_dump(boolval(false));`
`var_dump(!!$argv);`

Comment: Or just `echo false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the examples in the documentation, this would be the way to show boolean values:

```
echo 'false: '.(boolval(false) ? 'true' : 'false')."\n";
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php

The manual also says:

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
>   converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

From the [php manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
>   converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.

use

```
echo $boolres ? 'true' : 'false';
```